# Wicket and Java : Changes to page do not persist

Tags: java, wicket

I am a n00b when it comes to Wicket, as i started earlier this week. What i am trying to do is display a list of people on a page with radio buttons describing their gender. Now the radio buttons are selected properly when the page loads, however when i submit the page, the changes (if any are made) are not persisted. I am used to asp.net MVC so i am familiar with Model Binding, but wicket is kind of alien to me and to be honest, there isnt much documentation relating to this specific problem. So if you guys would be so kind as to check over my code i would very much appreciate it.
Any comments and/or fixes would also be appreciated.

**.java code**

```
public class FlightInfo extends WebPage 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private ListView<GuestInfo> guestRecordListView;

public FlightInfo() {
    this.init();
}

private void init() 
{
    FeedbackPanel feedbackPanel = new FeedbackPanel("flightinfo.errormessages");
    add(feedbackPanel);

    final SearchResponse searchResponse = ((DciSession)super.getSession()).getSearchResponse();

    //Data lists
    guestRecordListView = new ListView<GuestInfo>("guestRecordListView", searchResponse.getObj().getGuestList())
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static final long MALE = 1L;
        private static final long FEMALE = 2L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<GuestInfo> item)
        {
            item.add(new Label("guestRecordNameListItem", new PropertyModel<String>(item.getModel().getObject(), "Name")));

            String gender = item.getModel().getObject().getGender();

            IModel genderModel = new PropertyModel<String>(item.getModel(), "Gender");

            final RadioGroup<String> guestTypeRadioGroup = new RadioGroup("radio-passengerType", genderModel);
            item.add(guestTypeRadioGroup);

            final Model mModel = new Model(new PersonGenderXRef(item.getModel().getObject(), MALE));
            final Model fModel = new Model(new PersonGenderXRef(item.getModel().getObject(), FEMALE));
            final Model cModel = new Model(new PersonGenderXRef(item.getModel().getObject(), CHILD));

            guestTypeRadioGroup.add(new Radio("radio-male", mModel));
            guestTypeRadioGroup.add(new Radio("radio-female", fModel));
            guestTypeRadioGroup.add(new Radio("radio-child", cModel));

            if(gender.toUpperCase().equals("M"))
            {
                guestTypeRadioGroup.setModel(mModel);
            }
            else 
            {
                if (gender.toUpperCase().equals("F"))
                {
                    guestTypeRadioGroup.setModel(fModel);                   
                }
                else
                {
                    if (gender.toUpperCase().equals("C"))
                    {
                        guestTypeRadioGroup.setModel(cModel);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    };

    //Buttons
    Button continueButton = new Button("input.submitChanges");

    Form form = new Form("form.reviewAndEditForm")
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        protected void onSubmit()
        {       

            try
            {                       
                List<GuestInfo> guests = (List<GuestInfo>) guestRecordListView.getModelObject();
                List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
                //Construct people list
                for(int i = 0; i < guests.size(); i++)
                {
                    people.add(guests.get(i).getPerson());
                }
                //Submit request
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }           
    };
    add(form);

    form.add(continueButton);
    form.add(guestRecordListView);
    form.add(flightRecordListView);
}

private final void saveStuff(ListView<GuestInfo> data)
{
    ListView<GuestInfo> dataview2 = data;
}
}
```

Other class that is mentioned

```
public class PersonGenderXRef implements Serializable
{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private GuestInfo guest;
private long gender;

public PersonGenderXRef(GuestInfo guest, long gender)
{
    this.guest = guest;
    this.gender = gender;
}

public GuestInfo guest()
{
    return this.guest;
}

public void setGuest(GuestInfo guest)
{
    this.guest = guest;
}

public long getGender()
{
    return this.gender;
}

public void setGender(long gender)
{
    this.gender = gender;
}
}
```

And here is the markup

```
                    <table id="guestTable">
                        <tr>
                            <th width="20"><!-- <input id="select_all_guests" type="checkbox" /> --></th>
                            <th width="150"><b>Name</b></th>
                            <th colspan="3"><b>Guest Type<span style="color:red">*</span></b></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr wicket:id="guestRecordListView">
                            <td width="20"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                            <td width="150"><span wicket:id="guestRecordNameListItem"></span></td>
                            <wicket:container wicket:id="radio-passengerType">
                                <td width="80"><input wicket:id="radio-male" type="radio" />Male</td>
                                <td width="80"><input wicket:id="radio-female" type="radio" />Female</td>
                            </wicket:container>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model of the RadioGroup should point to the property on an underlying bean which is persisted to the database.

For example, suppose you have a model for a root object which knows how to load and persist changes to the database (or the changes are persisted on form submit):

```
IModel personModel = new PropertyModel<Person>(item.getModel(), "person");
```

You want the radio group to be a sub-property of the person which is the gender property:

```
IModel genderModel = new PropertyModel<String>(personModel, "gender")
```

Comment: new RadioGroup("radio-passengerType", genderModel)

Comment: "For example, suppose you have a model for a root object which knows how to load and persist changes to the database (or the changes are persisted on form submit):" I assume this means that the objects need getters and setters? Reason im asking is because its the only thing i havent tried. Ive added your code, and in the onsubmit method i added validate() and updateFormComponentModels() and still no persisted changes.

Comment: Wicket is only a UI framework. It does not provide a mechanism for interacting directly with the database. The model and form submit code must provide some persistence mechanism. Where does the item's model (of type GuestInfo) come from? The property models provided in the above answer interact with the ListItem's model, and will call getObject().getPerson().setGender(...) internally as the form is processed. Once the values are set on the object, it's up to your form submit code to persist the changes. Are you using a persistence framework, and ORM solution, such as databinder and hibernate?

Comment: I have a dao object that gets the information. But the changes cant be submitted from the page directly to the database, they have a chain of layers they have to go through to before a request is submitted to the database. Id have no problem doing that, but im just trying to get the changes from the page to the model.

Comment: Use the models above to get the changes from the page onto the item's model object.

Comment: You need to also remove the code which replaces the radio group's model: guestTypeRadioGroup.setModel(...). This is overriding the model specified in the constructor.

Comment: I took out what i thought was the default selection code (as per your suggestion) and that serialization class final Model mModel = new Model(new PersonGenderXRef(item.getModel().getObject(), MALE)); and replaced it with final Model mModel = new Model(MALE); and it works.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just think of the model as a pointer to the field which the component represents. When you call setModel(...), you are not changing the value of the field, you are changing the pointer (replacing it with a dummy pointer which just holds a static value instead of referencing the field). If you wanted to change the underlying value, you would call setModelObject(). If you want to set a default without changing the underlying object, you will have to introduce a more sophisticated mechanism.